# How to automatize to draw a broken line with intersections with two straight lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

How to automatize next code using `\foreach` or any other  methods for drawing broken line with intersections with two straight lines

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [fill=gray!50] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
            \draw [thick] (-0.5,0) -- (0,4) -- (0.5,0);
            % how to automatize next code using \foreach or any other  methods
            \draw (-0.5,0) -- ++(30:1.077) -- ++(150:0.90)  -- ++ (30:0.8)  -- ++(150:0.7)  -- ++ (30:0.6) -- ++(150:0.53) -- ++ (30:0.45) --  ++(150:0.38) -- ++ (30:0.33) -- ++(150:0.29) -- ++ (30:0.26) -- ++(150:0.23) -- ++ (30:0.205) -- ++(150:0.18);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My not so good solution with `intersections` library

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=gray!50] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
        \draw [thick, name path = Line1] (-0.5,0) -- (0,  4);
        \draw [thick, name path = Line2] ( 0 , 4) -- (0.5,0);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,7} {
        \draw [name path=\x]  (-0.5,0.5*\x) -- (0.5,0.5*\x) ;
        \ifodd\x
            \def\lo{1}
            \def\lt{2}
            \def\lft{left}
            \def\rgt{right}  
        \else
           \def\lo{2}
           \def\lt{1}
           \def\lft{right}
           \def\rgt{left}  
        \fi
        \node [{\rgt}, name intersections={of={\x} and {Line\lt}, by={\x} }] at ({\x}) {{\x}};
        \node [{\lft}, name intersections={of={\x} and {Line\lo}, by={C\x} }] at ({C\x}) {{C\x}};
        } 
        \draw (-0.5,0) foreach \x in {1,...,7} { -- (\x)};
        \draw (0.5,0) foreach \x in {1,...,7} { -- (C\x)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\draw(-100:3.6)foreach\i in{1,...,20}{--(-80:4*.81^\i)--(-100:3.6*.81^\i)};`

Comment: @Symbol1 Could you write an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Besides a mathematical solution by [Symbol 1 in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386843/how-to-automatize-to-draw-a-broken-line-with-intersections-with-two-straight-lin#comment958652_386843) you can of course let PGF/TikZ do the math.

If you don't need the zig-zag lines to be on one path you can just use one loop that finds the interesctions (with the `intersection` coordinate system using `intersection of`) and mirror the found coordinates to draw the other part.

```
\draw [thick] (-0.5,0) coordinate (l)
              -- (0,4) coordinate (t)
            -- (0.5,0) coordinate (r);
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
   \draw [thin, red!\the\numexpr9*\i\relax!blue]
     (l) -- (intersection of r--t and l--{[shift=(30:1)]l})
     coordinate (r) ([xscale=-1]l) -- ([xscale=-1]r)
     (r) -- (intersection of l--t and r--{[shift=(150:1)]r})
     coordinate (l) ([xscale=-1]l) -- ([xscale=-1]r);
```

If you really want to use another color as the triangle I'd recommend putting the whole `\foreach` block in a `path picture` so that it gets clipped against the path.

If you need each zig-zag line on one complete path, we can do this too:

```
\draw (l) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate (l@) -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift=(30:1)]  l@})
     coordinate (r@) -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)] r@})
  };
\draw (r) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate (r@) -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)] r@})
     coordinate (l@) -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift=(30:1)]  l@})
  };
```

or again with `xscale = -1` with a bunch of named coordinates:

```
\draw [line join=bevel] (l) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate[alias=l@\i] (l@)
     -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift=(30:1)]l@})
     coordinate[alias=r@\i] (r@)
     -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)]r@})
  };
\draw [line join=bevel] (r) -- ([xscale=-1]r@0) foreach \i in {1,...,11} {
       -- ([xscale=-1]l@\i) -- ([xscale=-1]r@\i)
  };
```

---

But a solution with the `intersections` library can be looped, too.

```
\draw [thick] (-0.5,0) coordinate[alias=l@] (l)
              -- (0,4) coordinate (t)
            -- (0.5,0) coordinate (r) [name path=ltr];

\foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
  \path [overlay, path only, name path=l@]
    ([shift=(30:\pgflinewidth)]l@) -- ++(30:2);
  \path [overlay, path only, name path=r@,
    name intersections={of=ltr and l@, by={[alias=r@\i]r@}}]
    ([shift=(150:\pgflinewidth)]r@) -- ++(150:2);
  \tikzset{name intersections={of=ltr and r@, by={[alias=l@\i]l@}}}
}

\draw (l) foreach\i in{0,...,11} { -- (r@\i) -- (l@\i) };
\draw (r) foreach\i in{0,...,11} { -- ([xscale=-1]r@\i) -- ([xscale=-1]l@\i) };
```

As with all other approaches, in one iteration we calculate (or draw) the zig as well as the zag lines. That way, you don't need to figure out which part you're doing.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  initial drawing/.default={}{},
  initial drawing/.code 2 args={
    \draw [fill=gray!50] (180:1)
      arc [start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=1] -- cycle;
    \draw [thick] (-0.5,0) coordinate[#1] (l)
                  -- (0,4) coordinate (t)
                -- (0.5,0) coordinate (r) [#2];}]
\matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm] {

% find and draw to intersections
% use xscale to mirror
% → separate paths
\tikzset{initial drawing}
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
   \draw [thin, red!\the\numexpr9*\i\relax!blue]
     (l) -- (intersection of r--t and l--{[shift=(30:1)]l})
     coordinate (r) ([xscale=-1]l) -- ([xscale=-1]r)
     (r) -- (intersection of l--t and r--{[shift=(150:1)]r})
     coordinate (l) ([xscale=-1]l) -- ([xscale=-1]r);
&

% find intersections and draw
% the same for the other line
\tikzset{initial drawing}
\draw (l) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate (l@) -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift= (30:1)] l@})
     coordinate (r@) -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)] r@})
  };
\draw (r) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate (r@) -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)] r@})
     coordinate (l@) -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift= (30:1)] l@})
  };
&

% find intersections and draw
% save coordinates for xscale other line
\tikzset{initial drawing}
\draw (l) foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
     coordinate[alias=l@\i] (l@)
     -- (intersection of r--t and l@--{[shift=(30:1)]l@})
     coordinate[alias=r@\i] (r@)
     -- (intersection of l--t and r@--{[shift=(150:1)]r@})
  };
\draw (r) -- ([xscale=-1]r@0) foreach \i in {1,...,11} {
       -- ([xscale=-1]l@\i) -- ([xscale=-1]r@\i)
  };
&

% find intersections with library
% draw both lines separately
\tikzset{initial drawing={alias=l@}{name path=ltr}}
\foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
  \path [overlay, path only, name path=l@]
    ([shift=(30:\pgflinewidth)]l@) -- ++(30:2);
  \path [overlay, path only, name path=r@,
    name intersections={of=ltr and l@, by={[alias=r@\i]r@}}]
    ([shift=(150:\pgflinewidth)]r@) -- ++(150:2);
  \tikzset{name intersections={of=ltr and r@, by={[alias=l@\i]l@}}}
}

\draw (l) foreach\i in{0,...,11} { -- (r@\i) -- (l@\i) };
\draw (r) foreach\i in{0,...,11} { -- ([xscale=-1]r@\i) -- ([xscale=-1]l@\i) };
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]